# Programatically determine shared libraries in use by running application

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries, ldd

Is it possible to (and, if so, how does one) determine the shared libraries of an application that are used by an application *at runtime*?  Basically, can I programmatically obtain the the output of `ldd`?  Preferred C/C++ solution does not just jump to execute ldd on the command-line.

Consider the following:
I have a driver application that calls `doAction()` from a shared library `libfoo`.  I compile the application once and then set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to an appropriate directory containing a `libfoo` with the `doAction()` symbol defined.  This way, I can have multiple implementations of `doAction()` in different `libfoo`s but only ever compile an application once.

A real world example would be a professor having a class of students implement `doAction()`.  Instead of compiling a test harness against each student's implementation of `doAction()`, the students submit a shared library and the professor can simply change `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to evaluate each student.

My goal in obtaining the library currently being used is to perform an `md5sum` on the library at runtime to ensure I'm calling the correct library.  In the contrived example, all students would submit the `md5sum` of their library and the professor could match the running executable + shared library (database lookup, log to file, ...) to the student, to prevent an accident in setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` effecting another student's grade (forgot to change `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to David's directory and ran again with Bill's `libfoo`).

Comment: Your example has other solutions, not sure if they apply to your original question. For example, the library could have a function to uniquely identify it. The application could dynamically load the library (via `dlopen`) and perform the checksum then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it looks like you're using something UNIX-y, just use `dlopen` instead of dynamically linking your driver app against the missing symbol.

Full sequence is:

1. iterate over all submitted .so library filenames somehow (maybe you have one directory with *studentname.so* or something)
2. load each library
3. get the entry point function
4. call it
5. unload library (optional, I guess)

like so:

```
void *lib = dlopen(filename, RTLD_LOCAL);
void *libfun = dlsym(lib, "doAction");
if (libfun == NULL)
    cout << "student failed by not providing doAction() in " << filename << endl;
else {
    void (*doAction)(void) = (void (*)(void)) libfun;
    // no, I can't remember the correct syntax for casting to function pointer
    cout << "calling " << filename << ":doAction()" << endl;
    doAction();
    // is there some way to tell if it succeeded?
    cout << "unloading " << filename << endl;
    dlclose(lib);
}
```

Notes:

- if the interface is the same in each case (ie, `void (*)()`), you could make this configurable by directory name and symbol name, and it'd work for more than one test
- in fact, if the interface is NOT what you expect, the function pointer cast will do horrible things, so careful with this
- finally, if the student used C++, their function name symbol will be mangled.  Tell them to declare the entry-point as `extern "C" void doAction()` to avoid that.
- the `RTLD_LOCAL` flag should stop anything in one student's library interfering with another (if you don't unload), but there are other flags it may be sensible to add

  - specifically, `RTLD_NOW` will cause `dlopen` to fail if the student lib has an unresolved external reference it can't figure out (so you can handle it gracefully, by failing them): otherwise your program may just crash when you call `doAction`.

---

Although I think the above is *better* than the solution you're directly asking for help with, I did also find a reference to `dl_iterate_phdr` while double-checking the docs. If you're on Linux specifically, and if the `dl_phdr_info.dlpi_name` is actually the filename ... you might be able to get it that way.

I still think it's much uglier, though.

Comment: Granted, I have not tried this yet, but do I need to worry about C++ name mangling in regards to the symbol name argument to `dlsym()`?

Comment: I wish there were something POSIX, but `dlopen` and friends seem to be widely implemented and may work for my purpose.

Comment: According to the Linux manpage I have handy, this is POSIX.1-2001, but I've only used it on SunOS and Linux myself.

Comment: Ah, I typo'd into opengroup.org.  I see `dlopen` now.  Excellent!

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Linux, you can use the `dl_iterate_phdr` function:

> The dl_iterate_phdr() function allows an application to inquire at run time to find out which shared objects it has loaded.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/dl_iterate_phdr

Answer (score 2):

At runtime, it is not an application, it is a process.

If the process has pid 1234, you can get its memory map by reading `/proc/1234/maps` (or `/proc/1234/smaps` which is more detailed). That map lists in particular [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap)-ed files (notably shared libraries). From inside the application, read `/proc/self/maps`

Try

```
   grep so /proc/self/maps
```

to have an idea of what I mean.

By the way, if you have an address, the [dladdr](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dladdr) function gives information about the nearest symbol and shared object...

#### addenda

And as Rob Mayoff [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9038580/841108), [dl_iterate_phdr](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dl_iterate_phdr) is probably the best solution on Linux

Comment: I'm gleaning that `dladdr()` is the way to go, as this application could be run on a system without a `procfs`.

Comment: But `dladdr` is not listing all the shared libraries, only the one containing the address you pass to it.

Comment: `dlopen()` not `dladdr()`, my typo.

Answer (score 1):

If this is Linux (I doubt there's a generic POSIX way to do this but I could be wrong), you may be interested in the contents of /proc/(pid)/maps. This gives the mapped memory ranges for your process and you could search for which of the ranges your md5sum() function's address falls in.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in linux/unix, you could use [strace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) like `strace -o strace.log -f students_binary` .  Strace traces all system calls, including the calls to open a library.   Then you could parse `strace.log` for all openings of any file and perform the `md5sum` on all open files.