# Portable way to determine path to dynamic library opened with dlopen

Tags: c++, c, posix, shared-libraries, dlopen

I'm searching for a portable (POSIX) way to determine the path to a library opened with `dlopen()`.  Functions like `dl_iterate_phdr()` and `dladdr()` are not portable.

Some `man` pages detail the path taken by `dlopen()` to find libraries to open (`ld.so.cache`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, /lib, /usr/lib, ...), so checking all of these directories *could* be possible, but not portable.  For example, under Linux, I'd need a way to parse `ld.so.cache` but under Mac OS X, there is no such concept.

Please see a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038303/programatically-determine-shared-libraries-in-use-by-running-application) for detail on why I want to do this, since using `dlopen` is ill-advised in the general case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not really any way to do what you want portably. Really it's probably a bad idea to use `dlopen` without an absolute path, and also a bad idea to use it for anything other than modules intended to be loaded with `dlopen` (created by and distributed with either your own project itself or another library your application uses). If you use it with the system library search path and libraries "already present" on the system, you run serious risks of loading the wrong version or even the wrong library with the same name. As long as you always pass an absolute path to `dlopen`, you can be sure you know exactly what file was loaded (or better yet, know exactly what file *will be loaded* before it gets loaded).

If this answer doesn't help, perhaps you could better explain what you're trying to achieve..

Comment: Sounds like absolute path is the way to go, but one must ensure that the absolute path is correct, because `dlopen` will start down its search paths otherwise. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038303/programatically-determine-shared-libraries-in-use-by-running-application for explicit detail on what I'd like to accomplish.

Comment: OK, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not the right approach for what you're doing there. Instead you should just pass the full pathname of the student's shared library file to your program, and then it can load it with the full pathname.

Comment: @greg: dlopen only searches the library path if the name given does NOT contain a "/" character.  If it contains a "/" it's treated as a file path (passed directly to open) and if that file does not exit, it won't look anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that there isn't one.  This is one place where
Windows is in advance of Unix.